creating playlist feature for astrology course app
i am currently amidst of migrating from flutterflow to flutter and i am encountering state management issues where the page that contains videos for creating playlist by normal user has a checkbox and on selecting the checkbox it should retrieve the video post item with relevant information and currently that doesn't work here's the relevant checkbox code
class PostItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final QueryDocumentSnapshot post;

  const PostItem({super.key, required this.post});

  u/override
  _PostItemState createState() => _PostItemState();
}

class _PostItemState extends State<PostItem> {
  late Contentfeed2Model _model;
  late DocumentReference _documentReference;

  bool? isChecked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _model = createModel(context, () => Contentfeed2Model());
    isChecked = false; // Initial checkbox state
    _documentReference = widget.post.reference;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var post = widget.post;
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    context.pushNamed(
                      'profilevisiting',
                      queryParameters: {
                        'postuser': serializeParam(
                          post['post_user'],
                          ParamType.String,
                        ),
                        'profilepic': serializeParam(
                          post['postuser_photo'],
                          ParamType.String,
                        ),
                        'userpostref': serializeParam(
                          post.reference,
                          ParamType.DocumentReference,
                        ),
                        'postuserref': serializeParam(
                          post['post_useref'],
                          ParamType.DocumentReference,
                        ),
                      }.withoutNulls,
                    );
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage:
                            NetworkImage(post['postuser_photo'] ?? ''),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text(post['post_user'] ?? 'Unknown'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Checkbox(
                  value: _model.ischecked,
                  onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _model.ischecked = newValue ?? false;
                    });

                    // Handle checkbox state change here
                    if (newValue == true) {
                      String videoId = post['postID'];
                      String thumbnail = post['thumbnail'];
                      String videoUrl = post['video_url'];
                      String postUser = post['post_user'];

                      // Add the selected item to the list
                      _model.checkboxCheckedItems.add({
                        'postID': videoId,
                        'thumbnail': thumbnail,
                        'videoUrl': videoUrl,
                        'postUser': postUser,
                      } as UserPosts2Record);
                    } else {
                      // Remove the item from the list if unchecked
                      _model.checkboxCheckedItems.removeWhere(
                        (element) => element.postID == post['postID'],
                      );
                    }
                  },
                )

model of the page
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import 'contentfeed2_widget.dart' show Contentfeed2Widget;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Contentfeed2Model extends FlutterFlowModel<Contentfeed2Widget> {
  ///  Local state fields for this page.

  bool ischecked = false;

  bool ischeckedfree = false;

  bool isliked = false;

  bool paid = false;

  ///  State fields for stateful widgets in this page.

  final unfocusNode = FocusNode();
  // Stores action output result for [Firestore Query - Query a collection] action in Button widget.
  PurchaseHistoryRecord? boughtornot;
  // State field(s) for Checkbox widget.
  Map<UserPosts2Record, bool> checkboxValueMap = {};
  List<UserPosts2Record> get checkboxCheckedItems =>
      checkboxValueMap.entries.where((e) => e.value).map((e) => e.key).toList();

  // Stores action output result for [Firestore Query - Query a collection] action in Checkbox widget.
  UserPosts2Record? checkboxpostid;
  // Stores action output result for [Backend Call - Create Document] action in IconButton widget.
  PlaylistRecord? makeplaylistpurchasedpost;
  // Stores action output result for [Backend Call - Create Document] action in IconButton widget.
  PlaylistactualRecord? makeplaylist;

  @override
  void initState(BuildContext context) {}

  @override
  void dispose() {
    unfocusNode.dispose();
  }
}

playlist creation button on the videos page
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.playlist_play, color: Color(0xFF420181)),
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_model.ischecked || _model.ischeckedfree) {
                  var playlistactualRecordReference =
                      PlaylistactualRecord.collection.doc(
                          '$currentUserDisplayName${getCurrentTimestamp.toString()}');
                  await playlistactualRecordReference.set({
                    ...createPlaylistactualRecordData(
                      playlistId:
                          '$currentUserDisplayName${getCurrentTimestamp.toString()}',
                      createdBy: currentUserReference,
                      playlistName:
                          '$currentUserDisplayName${getCurrentTimestamp.toString()}',
                      coverimage: '',
                    ),
                    ...mapToFirestore(
                      {
                        'postid': _model.checkboxCheckedItems
                            .map((e) => e.postID)
                            .toList(),
                        'videopostpost': _model.checkboxCheckedItems
                            .map((e) => e.videoUrl)
                            .toList(),
                        'astrologer': _model.checkboxCheckedItems
                            .map((e) => e.postUser)
                            .toList(),
                      },
                    ),
                  });
                  _model.makeplaylist =
                      PlaylistactualRecord.getDocumentFromData({
                    ...createPlaylistactualRecordData(
                      playlistId:
                          '$currentUserDisplayName${getCurrentTimestamp.toString()}',
                      createdBy: currentUserReference,
                      playlistName:
                          '$currentUserDisplayName${getCurrentTimestamp.toString()}',
                      coverimage: '',
                    ),
                    ...mapToFirestore(
                      {
                        'postid': _model.checkboxCheckedItems
                            .map((e) => e.postID)
                            .toList(),
                        'videopostpost': _model.checkboxCheckedItems
                            .map((e) => e.videoUrl)
                            .toList(),
                        'astrologer': _model.checkboxCheckedItems
                            .map((e) => e.postUser)
                            .toList(),
                      },
                    ),
                  }, playlistactualRecordReference);

                  context.pushNamed(
                    'createplaylist',
                    queryParameters: {
                      'createplaylist': serializeParam(
                        _model.makeplaylist,
                        ParamType.Document,
                      ),
                    }.withoutNulls,
                    extra: <String, dynamic>{
                      'createplaylist': _model.makeplaylist,
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  // Show a message or handle the case when nothing is selected
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                        content: Text('Please select at least one item')),
                  );
                }
              },
            )

and the create playlist page accepts this parameter
class CreateplaylistWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateplaylistWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.createplaylist,
  });

i have tried learning about state management solution like bloc changing type casting for firebase and changing query params
